# ESP8266 nodemcu resolving raspberry's local dns

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi2, esp8266, nodemcu, mdns

I'm having an issue with connecting the esp module on the raspberry via `mqtt`. After a lot of search I think I am kinda lost now.

So here's the problem

I have setup my raspberry's local dns to work as cubex.local, I followed the instructions here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/

Everything seems to be working fine on this end...
I can use the `cubex.local` on the local network to have ssh and ftp access to the raspberry but when it comes to the esp trying to resolve that address it keeps failing.

this is the code running on the esp:

```
function broker_connect()
 m = mqtt.Client(ID, 120, BRUSER, BRPWD)
 m:on("message", on_message_received)
 m:on("connect", on_connect)
 m:on("offline", on_mqqt_offline)

 tmr.alarm(0, 1000, 1,function() 
 print("Connecting to MQTT broker at "..HOST..". Please wait...")
 m:connect( HOST , PORT, 0)
end)
```

and the output:

> Connecting to MQTT broker at cubex.local. Please wait...
>   DNS retry 1!
>   DNS retry 2!
>   DNS retry 3!
>   DNS retry 4!
>   DNS Fail!
>   Connecting to MQTT broker at cubex.local. Please wait...
>   DNS retry 1!
>   DNS retry 2!
>   DNS retry 3!
>   DNS retry 4!
>   DNS Fail!
>   Connecting to MQTT broker at cubex.local. Please wait...
>   DNS retry 1!
>   DNS retry 2!
>   DNS retry 3!
>   DNS retry 4!
>   DNS Fail!

The host variable holds the `cubex.local` and the port is 1883.
When I use the raspberry's IP which is 192.168.0.3 everything works fine.
Still I fail to understand why it keeps failing to resolve the address.

Comment: Did you try to edit you /etc/hosts file with the IP address and the "domain name" ?

Comment: well yeah, the domain works like a charm while accessing it from anywhere else except the esp, that was that primarily lead me to believe that the raspberry is ok on that end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hostname `cubex.local` is registered through mDNS, but mqtt query a DNS to resolve the hostname.

One option could be to use a DNS proxy to mDNS like [mdns-proxy](https://github.com/wisq/mdns-proxy), an other one is to modify nodemcu to query the mDNS directly.